# How to send a Gig of data through a Java socket?

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I'm trying to send a gigabyte sized byte array through a Java socket to my client in C#, but about 580k entries in my data is lost. I set every entry in my array to 10, but at a certain point they become 0s.

My Java code:

```
OutputStream outputStream = objSocket.getOutputStream();

byte[] dataBytesLength = new byte[4];
int toSendLen = dataBytes.length;

dataBytesLength[0] = (byte)(toSendLen & 0xff);
dataBytesLength[1] = (byte)((toSendLen >> 8) & 0xff);
dataBytesLength[2] = (byte)((toSendLen >> 16) & 0xff);
dataBytesLength[3] = (byte)((toSendLen >> 24) & 0xff);

outputStream.write(dataBytesLength);
outputStream.write(dataBytes);
```

My C# code:

```
byte[] receivedLengthBytes = new byte[4];
Socket.Receive(receivedLengthBytes);

int receivedLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(receivedLengthBytes, 0);

byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[receivedLength];
Socket.Receive(receivedBytes);
```

If I loop over the array of received bytes, everything after 589824 is 0. I am not sure why this data loss is occurring, and splitting this into many 500k chunks is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: You probably have to repeat reading from the socket until you got all data. The documentation for Socket.Receive should have details about various overloads of the Receive method, about how it can tell you how many bytes have been received, etc...

Comment: You are **ignoring** the return value from `Socket.Receive`... Data transfer isn't instantaneous and you will need multiple receives to get all data.

Comment: Thanks guys, you were right. Checking the return value of .Receive showed it was only getting 589825 bytes, so I placed it in a do/while loop. It works great now.